# Sonarqube Pull Request integration with multiple builds

Tags: sonarqube, sonarcloud

We have a scenario where a single VSTS Pull Request can trigger multiple builds.  The issue is that SonarCloud only creates a single code quality status against the PR which seems to only link to one of the builds.

Is it supported to have multiple builds and use the pull request integration?  If so, should there not be 2 status gates?

When you click the link, it takes you to one of the builds in SonarCloud and not the other.

Comment: Do you use the same SonarQube project key in both builds?

Comment: No - They are separate sonar projects